# @Html.ActionLink with an id for the link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have something like in MVC (I am using MVC c# using razor):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", new { id = item.ProjectID})
```

produces something like when I look at the source code:

```
<a href="/iDVI/Project/EditProject/535">Edit</a>
```

Note how 535 was the result of having item.ProjectID.
This is fine. What I like to do though is to put an id for this edit link. Something like:

```
<a href="/iDVI/Project/EditProject/535" id="Projectid">Edit</a>
```

How do I do this. I know using new{id=...} will create a id but and id is already used for what I intially needed to do.

I need to give an id to the link now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the signature of the method when you are using it.
When you wrote:

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", new { id = item.ProjectID})
```

you used the following overload:

> *HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string ActionName, object
>   routeValues)*

So this is why you were getting your item.ProjectID as a part of the url. It is a routeValue in this case.

The overload that you are looking for is probably this one:

> *HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string ActionName, object
>   routeValues, object htmlAttributes)*

Using this overload you specify that you want to use your variable item.ProjectID as a part of url as well as an attribute of the link:

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", new { id = item.ProjectID}, new { id = item.ProjectID })
```

If you actually want to spell out the name of the variable, you would write:

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", new { id = item.ProjectID}, new { id = @"Projectid" })
```

This gives you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", new { id = item.ProjectID }, new { id = "Projectid" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProject", null,  new { id = item.ProjectID})
```