# Trouble getting Entity in DB via primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a relatively simple webapp, but have run into a bit of a problem. After having searched low and high, I can't seem to find anyone with similar issues.

So the situation:

I have an entity:

```
public class Entity
{
        [Key]
        public int EntityId { get; set;}
        public string EntityName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Reason for the virtual `ICollection<OtherEntity>` is a many to many relationship between the two.

My `DbContext`:

```
public class WebAppDB : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public DbSet<Entity> Entities{ get; set; }

        public WebAppDB () : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static WebAppDB Create()
        {
                return new WebAppDB();
        }
    }
}
```

The default connection goes to an Amazon RDS SQL Server Express.

Around this I have created a repository:

```
public interface IEntityRepository
{
    IQueryable<Entity> AlEntitiss { get; }
    IQueryable<Entity> AllEntitissIncluding(params Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[] includeProperties);
    Entity FindEntity(int id);
    void InsertOrUpdateEntity(Entity entity);
    void DeleteEntity(int id);
    void Save();
}

public class EntityRepository : IEntityRepository
{
    // handle to the database through the O.R.M. system.
    private WebAppDB context = new WebAppDB();

    public IQueryable<Entity> AllCEntitys
    {
        get { return context.Entitiss; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Entity> AllClassesIncluding(params Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
            IQueryable<Entity> query = context.Entitiss;

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            return query;
    }

    public Entity FindEntity(int id)
    {                    
        return context.Entitiss.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdateEntity(Entity Entity)
    {
            if (Entity.EntityId == 0)
            {
                context.Entitiss.Add(Entity);
            }
            else
            {
               context.Entry(Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
    }

    public void DeleteEntity(int id)
    {
            Entity Entity = FindEntity(id);
            context.Entitys.Remove(Entity);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem lies in the fact that I can get a list of the entities I have in the database and load them just fine into Selectlists or similar structures.
I can also get specific Entities based on other properties than the primary key.

But I can't get a single entity from the database using the primary key as my entry point. I have tried using `DbSet.Entities.SingleOrDefault()`, `.Single()`, `.Find()`

I have also tried to retrieve it using

```
DbSet.Entities.ToList().Where(x => x.EntityId == id)
```

I have moved from 2 data contexts down to 1, I have checked that I am referencing the same version of the EF in all projects in the solution (have a separate project for the entities).

After having read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148263/entity-framework-dbset-find-throws-exception), I fiddled with the Lazy loading, but no effect.

So I am running out of ideas and places to look.

If you need more information I will provide it to the best of my ability.

Thank you for reading and helping.

Update1:

I have tried moving to a local database with no luck, and it seems what I earlier described with loading lists of Entities working was exaggerated. They too don't load consistently when called.

Update 2:

Having used the SQL profiler to determine that not all calls from the controllers where executed on the database, I tried transplanting the entities to a fresh MVC project. Unfortunately the problem persists and I am out of ideas as this point.

Update 3:
After some more investigation and some help from Gert Arnold it has turned out that I misdiagnosed the initial problem. Due to poor coding practices it was not 1 central problem, but several separate problems all exhibiting similar characteristics that led me to the wrong conclusion that the EF was at fault. I am sorry to have wasted anyones time with this.

Comment: What is returned when you call FindEntity(id)?

Comment: it returns Null. And I am certain the entityId I am looking for exist in the DB.

Comment: @Nephross Can you see what queries are run on the server?

Comment: @silkfire I don't quite know how to do that, but will find out and get back to you.

Comment: @Nephross You have to use SQL Profiler whilst you run your code. It's accessible from a menu in the Manager.

Comment: @silkfire Ok, so I have been trying to run the SQL profiler while running the app, and it seems the dbcontext is really inconsistent about when it calls the db for some reason. Sometimes it calls and retrieves the data, even on primarykeys, othertimes it doesn't even call for the list. Is there a config somewhere I messed up?

Comment: @Nephross Okay, so it runs the query correctly in some cases, but it still retrieves `null`?

Comment: @silkfire No, it only retrieves null when the query doesn't get executed on the server. So in some cases it can retrieve the list of entities, but then can't do a find on a specific entity from that list- that query doesn't get executed. But it is inconsistent, because on other entities everything works fine. This is all when I run the app and interact with it. Trying to execute querys, be it on the repository or directly on a dbcontext from a unittest fails consistently, nothing goes through to the db.

Comment: @Nephross I noticed that you perform `ToList()` not as the last method in your execution chain. Also, why are you using `ToList()` when you're only interested in one `Entity`? Unless I'm missing something completely, I'd rewrite your query like this: `WebAppDB.DbSet.Entities.Find(id)`. Also I'm not certain why you in the context call you DbSet `Entities` but when you want to retrieve the entity you spell it out as `Entitys`?

Comment: @silkfire The .ToList() part is just to try something else, since I couldn't(and still cant) get.Find() to work consistently. Regarding naming, It is a sanitised example, I didn't get all the naming right, but in my app they are consistent.
I really don't know what is going on, but not all calls I make to the dbcontext get's executed it seems. I think the next step is to create a fresh project and transplant my logic, views and entitites to that and see if I can get it to work.. I can't think of some config where I screwed up the entityframework.

Comment: @Nephross What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @silkfire I am using EF6 specifically version 6.1.3 according the the nuget package manager. Though my reference says version 6.0.0.0

Comment: @Nephross Yeah that sounds strange as you're using the latest version of EF. Are you using all latest AWSSDKs from NuGet as well?

Comment: @silkfire the problem persist even when I switched to a localDb, so I very much doubt it is the AWSSDK. It was updated recently aswell, so I lean towards excluding that as the culprit.

Comment: @Nephross I'd recommend as you mentioned in a previous post to start a new project and test your entities from there. Have you tried implementing Code First by the way?

Comment: @silkfire It is implemented Code first in the current project. I will try to create a new project and see if a fresh set of configs can help any. I'll get back to you when that is done. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Nephross Okay that's great, I was just wondering. EDMX has been removed in the future version - EF7 - and Code First is the future, and the way to go. Please do, I'm curious how you'll solve this problem.

Comment: I have now tried transplanting the entities to a fresh project, but it is still inconsistent like before. I'm clueless as this point.

Comment: @GertArnold - I have yet to make any headway with it, so I would be immensely grateful if you would take a look at it.

Comment: OK, did you share the source anywhere?

Comment: No, it's for a small startup company, so I wanted to keep it inhouse as much as I could. Is there any way I can send it to you direct?

Comment: So far, I couldn't find anything unusual. I deployed your database to Sql Server (not localdb), ran the Seed method, connected to the context through Linqpad, and everything worked fine (FirstOrDefault, Find, ...). Nothing unusual. I could also access the data through a repository (e.g. `EntityRepository.FindAreaCity`). So the plot thickens...

Comment: hmm... interesting.. so when you run the app and login as admin, you can edit individual classes? That has so far been a sure nullpointer for me. I don't understand why I then have these issues. Can I have a bad install of Visual studio or something?

Comment: I didn't even get that far, because I was looking for the error you suspected to be there. But now I've been in the edit parts it appears to be as simple as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821892/html-actionlink-with-an-id-for-the-link. Always show the original exception message you get.

Comment: Hmm.. okay.. The trouble is that I didn't get the error at only that place, but several others aswell, so I assumed it had to be a more fundamental problem. I will go over the problem areas again and see if I can't find similar issues to sort of the grimlins. Thank you so much for looking it over! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class FindEntity(int id)
{
    //Want to find a specific student
    return context.Entitys.Find(id);
}
```

This one seems a bit weird to me, what's the `Class`? I think it should be `Student`. Anyway, check out the code sample below:

```
public Entity FindEntity(int id)
{
    return context.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EntityId == id); // note that it will return null if not found.
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I edited the post to reflect what is actually happening.
I tried the code sample, and it returns null like the other possibilities. But I know the Entity exist in the DB. It load correctly when I take the entire list and pass it as a Selectlist to a dropdownbox in a view for instance.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why your context.Entitys have value but your find method does not work. Can you check the column name in your table have the same name (EntityId)?

Comment: The column name correspond to the Entity property name. The Table SQL looks like this:

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entities] (
    [EntityId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityName]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Entities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EntityId] ASC)
   );